# UIDocument openWithCompletionHandler return NO for success

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, icloud, uidocument

I have this code:

```
[metaDoc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"UH OH");
    }
}];
```

Why would this ever return NO? For me it's returning NO even though in my

```
- (BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents 
                  ofType:(NSString *)typeName 
                   error:(NSError **)outError
```

method, I am always returning YES.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of reasons.  Override handleError:userInteractionPermitted: and either log the details, or set a breakpoint there.  You should see the exact error.